# Is "redeclare="true"" allowing me to change the attribute type for a subtype?

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

If I have :

```
<itemtype code="A">
    <attributes>
       <attribute qualifier="attributeA" type="java.lang.String">
         <modifiers .../>
       </attribute>
    </attributes>
</itemtype>
```

And

```
<itemtype code="B" extends="A">
    <attributes>
       <attribute qualifier="attributeA" redeclare="true" type="ATTENTION.HERE">
         <modifiers .../>
       </attribute>
    </attributes>
</itemtype>
```

What happens if I use "redeclare=true"? Will this let me change the attribute's type? For example, instead of `type="ATTENTION.HERE"`, can I write `type="java.lang.Integer`? And if so, will this "attributeA" be of type `Integer` only for B?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the *Redeclaring Attributes* section in https://help.sap.com/viewer/d0224eca81e249cb821f2cdf45a82ace/2005/en-US/8bffa9cc86691014bb70ac2d012708bc.html

Basically you can only make it a more specific subtype of what the parent class defined.

Comment: Yes, I've already read that but I wasn't sure if this was the answer. Thank you :D

Comment: You can redeclare an attribute to:
- Change its behaviour. For example, you can add a “unique” flag, or disallow writing.
- Make the type of the attribute more specific for subtypes.